# How to set correct group member for dockerized nodeJS application

Tags: node.js, docker, debian, raspbian, udev

I need to run a docker container with an application using [rpio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rpio) package.

I do not understand this part:

> By default the module will use /dev/gpiomem when using simple GPIO access. To access this device, your user will need to be a member of
>   the gpio group, and you may need to configure udev with the following
>   rule (as root):
>
> ```
> $ cat >/etc/udev/rules.d/20-gpiomem.rules <<EOF
> SUBSYSTEM=="bcm2835-gpiomem", KERNEL=="gpiomem", GROUP="gpio",
> MODE="0660" EOF
> ```
>
> For access to i²c, PWM, and SPI, or if you are running
>   an older kernel which does not have the bcm2835-gpiomem module, you
>   will need to run your programs as root for access to /dev/mem.

As I'm running my nodeJS application in a docker image/container, I don't understand how to set group member and which member name and where to call that udev rules command.

I'm very thankful for every explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docker user (should be the logged in user, e.g. "pi") needs to be in the "gpio" group.

```
# see all groups the user is assigned to
groups

# if the user is not assigned to gpio, run the following:
sudo adduser $(whoami) gpio
```

You need to make the device */dev/gpiomem* available inside the docker container.

```
# e.g.
docker run -d --device /dev/gpiomem <image>
```

Comment: All this has to be done in the terminal after logging into the pi, correct? It doesn't have to be done while building the docker image (Dockerfile).

Comment: Right, it has to be done on the raspberry it self. Same for the command you mentioned changing udev rules, except for you need to be the *root* user instead of *pi*. You can change to the root user by running `sudo su`.

Comment: What to do with `/dev/mem` which is mentioned at the end of my citation? It is needed to use I2C. Everything else is working.